# I can't mutate this struct I and I don't understand why

Tags: go, mutability

Consider the following gist [linked here](https://play.golang.org/p/yNKmDmY5b-):

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type StateTransition struct {
    msg Message
}

type Message interface {
    To() *string
}

type Transaction struct {
    data txdata
}

type txdata struct {
    Recipient *string
}

func (t Transaction) To() (*string) {
    return t.data.Recipient
}


func UnMask(n **string, k string) {
    *n = &k
} 

func main() {
    toField := "Bob"
    toPtr := &toField
    txd := txdata{toPtr}
    tx := Transaction{txd}
    st := StateTransition{tx}
    n1 := st.msg.To()
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s \n", *n1)
    UnMask(&n1, "Joe")
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s \n", *n1)
    n2 := st.msg.To()
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s \n", *n2)
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello, Bob 
Hello, Joe 
Hello, Bob
```

**Expected Output**

```
Hello, Bob
Hello, Joe
Hello, Joe
```

The result is the sequence "Bob, Joe, Bob" is printed whereas my intuition says that it should be "Bob, Joe, Joe" (this is also what i *want* it to print). Can someone experienced in go please explain to me enough about combining pointers, structs, and interfaces as they relate to this problem to give me some understanding about why I'm wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Post all code here directly. Never solely link to code. If the link goes down, your question becomes near useless to future readers.

Comment: And as far as the code itself code, maybe add some annotations/explanation so people can tell what it is you're actually trying to do? It's not particularly readable as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmask takes a pointer to a pointer, let's say pointer X to pointer Y, pointer Y points to the string value. Unmask then **changes** the pointer to which X is pointing to, Y is unchanged and points still to the same old string.

You can do this:

```
func UnMask(n **string, k string) {
    **n = k
}
```

or

```
func UnMask(n *string, k string) {
    *n = k
}
// ....
UnMask(n1, "Joe") // drop the '&'
```

Comment: I can't upvote this because of lack of reputation, but thanks. Anyone who can, please upvote the answer. @mkopriva

Comment: @martin, you may not be able to up vote, but if this was the answer to the question you can mark it as the correct answer.